# Storage and naming of log data

Tags: c#, data-structures, wpf

I'm in the process of rewriting a small application from console mode to a GUI mode.

The input is a file with log data from a measuring device:

```
...
00029;00044;00076;00044;00021
00309;00032;00037;00000;65535
00013;00016;00008;00007;00005
...
```

Each row of data represents 5 counters which summarize the range in which the measure fell, i.e. first column is "<40%", 2nd column is "[40-50[", and so on...

First row as example:

```
29 counts below 40% | 44 counts between 40% and 60% | 76 counts between 60% and 80%
44 counts between 80% and 90% | 21 counts between 90% and 100%
```

In the console application I used an array of integers to store each data row, putting each row array in a list. So far, so good... The application then used a for-loop to print out the values with descriptions to the console.

**My problem:**  I wanted to create a GUI with WPF and apply databinding.

But I have a conceptual issue with how to create the data binding to the arrays of integers and visual elements.

I have not had problems with data binding to single properties.  The challenge is due to the arrays.

I think I should create a class like this (could also be used as a ViewModel):

```
public class CounterRecords
{
    public List<CounterRecord> DataRecords { get; set; }
}
```

But how should I go about the `CounterRecord` class?
What's a clean / clear implementation of this object that I can bind to?

```
public class CounterRecord
{
    public int Range40 { get; set; }
    public int Range40_60 { get; set; }
    public int Range60_80 { get; set; }
    public int Range80_90 { get; set; }
    public int Range90_100 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Probably more appropriate on http://stackoverflow.com/questions you can ask the moderators to migrate this question.

Comment: @GlenH7: Thank you for your edit! Love it how it looks now :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Model` layer should reflect your data, so if your log data represents 5 separate values which indicate a counter of a range, then that's what your `Model` should look like.

Your `CounterRecord` data model looks fine to me, however some things to take into consideration when using WPF's data binding systems are:

- Are you going to be modifying the `CounterRecord` at runtime, and does this change need to be reflected in the UI? If so, you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on your `CounterRecord` class so it notifies the UI whenever it gets updated
- Are you going to be modifying the collection of `CounterRecord` objects at runtime, and does this change need to be reflected in the UI? If so, you will want to use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead of a `List<T>` for the same reasons

To bind to a collection instead of a single property, you'll want a UI control with an `ItemsSource` property, such as a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) or an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataRecords}" />
```

or

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataRecords}" />
```

Basically, an `ItemsSource` binding will loop through your collection and create a UI element for each item in the collection. That UI element may be a `DataGridRow`, a `TabItem`, a `ListBoxItem`, or even some custom element that you define with an `ItemTemplate`.

If you're interested, my blog has a [better explanation of an ItemsControl](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) than MSDN has, and it will probably help you understand the binding process to collections a bit better.

Comment: Thank you for the link to your blog! It helped me get a grasp at the `ItemsControl`. Neither the `CounterRecord` nor the collection of it will be modifed during runtime because the application is used to display a single logfile at a time.